# fpdf multicell is not generating same height

Tags: php, css, row, fpdf

I wrote below code , it working fine but multicell row heights are not working properly.I wrote below code , it working fine but multicell row heights are not working properly.I wrote below code , it working fine but multicell row heights are not working properly.

```
$x=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetY($x+1);

include_once("config.php");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM prd"); // using mysqli_query instead
$i = 1;
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$current_y = $pdf->GetY();
    $current_x = $pdf->GetX();

    $pdf->MultiCell(30, 5, $i, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = $pdf->GetY();
$prdid = $res[0];
        $empid = $res[1];
        $specification = $res[2];
$prn = $res[3];



$current_x = $current_x + 30;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y); 
    $pdf->MultiCell(30, 5, $empid, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;

$current_x = $current_x + 30;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(30, 5, $specification, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;

$current_x = $current_x + 30;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(30, 5, $prn, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;


 $i++;
    $pdf->SetY($end_y);

        }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

My Result :

[image: To see my result click here]

How to adjust row height automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

So a multi cell is essentially dynamic is height. The height you put into the function is a "row" height. So what happens is that fpdf goes to write the multi cell and let's say we defined the height to be 5, it'll create a "cell" of height 5 and start writing. Then it hits the hard stop at the width and goes "i have to create a new row", which it then adds a new "cell" of height 5 directly below the top "cell". This repeats until all text is written out. Obviously this is great for dynamic content, but has its own challenges that you have hit.

The path I normally take is to record the start point, write out the multi cell first, and then record the stopping point. You can then go back and write the other cells to make for better alignment. For this GetX, GetY, SetX, SetY will be  your friends. You can set heights and such dynamically with simple math.

The "lazy" option is to re-do the layout to allow for the document to scale, that being to take your way too long multi cell and put it UNDER the row so you'll have:
|1   |46   |PR2.....|
|really long text 
that will scale 
down here|
|2    |........

Hope that helps get you moving forward!